# DSRA3602E: Invalid driverType(providerType) parameter value specified

Tags: sql-server, jython, ibm-was

I am trying to run a python script for creating data-source but while running this script I am getting exception. I am using Websphere Application Server 8.5.5.8 & Linux RHEL 7& we are using SQL Server 2012.

SCRIPT CODE:

```
jp = AdminTask.listJDBCProviders('[-scope Node=%s]' % node)

if jp:
for jdp in jp.split(newline):
    pname = AdminConfig.showAttribute(jdp, "name")
    print pname
    if  (pname == "WebSphere embedded ConnectJDBC driver for MS SQL Server (XA)" or pname == "WebSphere embedded ConnectJDBC driver for MS SQL Server"):
        AdminConfig.remove(jdp)
        AdminConfig.save()

  AdminTask.createJDBCProvider('[-scope Node=%s -databaseType "SQL Server" -providerType "WebSphere embedded ConnectJDBC driver for MS SQL Server" -implementationType "XA data source" -name "WebSphere embedded ConnectJDBC driver for MS SQL Server (XA)" -description "IBM WebSphere Connect JDBC driver for MS SQL Server(XA)." -classpath ${WAS_LIBS_DIR}/sqlserver.jar;${WAS_LIBS_DIR}/base.jar;${WAS_LIBS_DIR}/util.jar;${WAS_LIBS_DIR}/spy.jar -nativePath ]' % node)
AdminConfig.save()

AdminTask.createJDBCProvider('[-scope Node=%s -databaseType "SQL Server" -providerType "WebSphere embedded ConnectJDBC driver for MS SQL Server" -implementationType "Connection pool data source" -name "WebSphere embedded ConnectJDBC driver for MS SQL Server" -description "IBM WebSphere Connect JDBC driver for MS SQL Server." -classpath ${WAS_LIBS_DIR}/sqlserver.jar;${WAS_LIBS_DIR}/base.jar;${WAS_LIBS_DIR}/util.jar;${WAS_LIBS_DIR}/spy.jar -nativePath ]' % node)
AdminConfig.save()
```

ERROR CODE:

```
WASX7017E: Exception received while running file "/root/Project/user_bin/CreateSQLJDBC.py"; exception information:    com.ibm.websphere.management.cmdframework.CommandValidationException
com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConfigServiceException: DSRA3602E:   Invalid driverType(providerType) parameter value specified: WebSphere  embedded ConnectJDBC driver for MS SQL Server
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JDBC provider (and corresponding embedded JDBC driver) are no longer present in WebSphere Application Server as of version 7.0.  Your question states that you are using version 8.5.5.8.  You will need to switch to a different JDBC driver and use its corresponding JDBC provider entries or create user-defined JDBC provider entries if not one of the JDBC providers with built-in information.

Websphere Application Server 8.5.5.8 has the following JDBC provider information as built-in for JDBC drivers for Microsoft SQL Server:

- "Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver"
- "Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver (XA)"
- "DataDirect ConnectJDBC type 4 driver for MS SQL Server"
- "DataDirect ConnectJDBC type 4 driver for MS SQL Server (XA)"

where the first two entries are for the JDBC driver from Microsoft, and the latter two are for the JDBC driver from Progress/DataDirect

Comment: Hello njr  I am using Microsoft SQL server jdbc driver(XA) but when i run script I had to set emulate two phase commit property to false otherwise it throws some error.

Comment: How can i enable emulate 2 phase property

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "set emulate two phase commit property to false" and post the exception stack of the failure you are seeing when you don't set that?

Comment: Hello njr, it's solved now actually i was setting the property emulate2phase commit for connection pool data-Source but for this we can set only false.

Thanks for your help.